# What part does the .WithRequired play in an EF Fluent API?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

If I have the following objects:

```
public class Application 
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class TestAccount
{
    public int TestAccountId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

EF Mapping looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
    .HasMany(a => a.TestAccounts)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Application)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The relationship between these two is that I can have applications with zero or many TestAccounts.

I am trying to describe a fk relationship between the two tables. Can someone explain what the ".WithRequired" does. I don't understand why this is needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that each `TestAccount` entity MUST have an `Application` entity associated with it.I suppose one way to put it is like this:

If in your DB, you have a foreign key to another table and that foreign key is NOT NULL, then use `WithRequired`, else if it can be NULL, then use `WithOptional`

Here is some documentation worth looking at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx